# Update manifest of AAD app via PowerShell script

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to create an azure active directory (AAD) application. Here is the command I use:

```
$uiApp = New-AzADApplication    -DisplayName $uiAppDisplayName `
                                -AvailableToOtherTenants $false `
                                -ReplyUrls $replyUrls `
                                -RequiredResourceAccess $requiredResourceAccess
```

How do I update the script to update manifest file (accessTokenAcceptedVersion value to 2)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, I created an application with the name **`demovenkat326`** with **`"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": null`** using the same command.

**Command:**

```
$uiAppDisplayName = "demovenkat326"
$replyUrls = @("https://jwt.ms")


# Create the Azure AD application
$uiApp = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $uiAppDisplayName `
                             -AvailableToOtherTenants $false `
                             -ReplyUrls $replyUrls `
```

**Portal:**

[image]

You can use the below commands to update the **`accessTokenAcceptedVersion`** to 2.

**Command:**

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Application.readwrite.all"
Welcome To Microsoft Graph!
    Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications
    $applicationId="< Your application object Id >"
    
    $params = @{
        Api = @{
            RequestedAccessTokenVersion = 2
        }
    }
    
    Update-MgApplication -ApplicationId $applicationId -BodyParameter $params
```

**Console:**
[image]

The above command was executed and successfully updated the version to 2.

**Portal:**
[image]

Comment: I see Update-MgApplication : The term 'Update-MgApplication' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

Comment: Why do I import Microsoft.Graph.Applications?

Comment: Hi @user989988 Please install the Microsoft graph module using the command `Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -AllowClobber -Force` After installing you need to import that module as `Update-MgApplication` is in that module to update the accesstokenacceptedversion.

Comment: I see error: Update-MgApplication : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. I'm the owner of this application. What permission is required to make this update?

Comment: Check your API permission has `application.readwrite.all` with grant admin consent in your application.